# Unsummarizing a dataset using Python

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following summarized dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
summarized_set = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[1,2,3],
                           'NumberOfObservations':[3,3,3]})
```

I'm looking for a way to convert the summarized values (number of observations) back to the actual observations.

```
observed_values = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]})
```

One thought I had was to iterate through the summarized set and multiply the value (as a list object) by the NumberOfObservations. Something like this:

```
z = []
z = z + ([1] * 3) + ([2] * 3) + ([3] * 3)
```

But, I'm wondering if there is a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
z = np.repeat(summarized_set['Value'],summarized_set['NumberOfObservations']).values.tolist()
print (z)
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Oh my very very exact to answer I have.

Comment: @jezrael, what is the correct usage for [`Series.repeat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.repeat.html). If OP wanted this answer in dataframe form?

Comment: I think it working same as `np.repeat`, so `summarized_set['Value'].repeat(summarized_set['NumberOfObservations']).values.tolist()`. I try add NaNs to `NumberOfObservations` and both methods failed (some pandas function working with `NaN`s nice, but here it is no difference)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following list comprehension to construct such a list:

```
[v
 for v,n in zip(summarized_set['Value'],summarized_set['NumberOfObservations'])
 for _ in range(n)]
```

So we can construct such dataframe with:

```
observed_values = pd.DataFrame({'Value':
    [v
     for v,n in zip(summarized_set['Value'],summarized_set['NumberOfObservations'])
     for _ in range(n)] })
```

This then produces:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'Value':
...     [v
...      for v,n in zip(summarized_set['Value'],summarized_set['NumberOfObservations'])
...      for _ in range(n)] })
   Value
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
5      2
6      3
7      3
8      3
```